# Remove displaying duplicate value from database

Tags: ios, sql, database, parent-child

I have parent-child relation question. When i answer the parent question, it displays parent along with child. When i answer the child it displays parent along with child. But if i answer both (parent & child) the child question displays twice. I know my query is wrong. But can't able to find. How to remove the duplicate data displaying from database

Comment: If you will simplify your sample/query may be more people will try to help you.

Comment: @Avt: I'm using this for getting answer. If i simplify i can't get answer from database

Comment: Can you add query output to the question?

Comment: @Avt: Can you help this

Comment: From your first image what line N2 or N3 should go away?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48361/discussion-between-user2967559-and-avt)

Comment: @Avt: Please help this if you know

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

```
DELETE
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
 DuplicateColumn1, DuplicateColumn2, DuplicateColumn3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to understand you query. Have you tried just to add DISTINCT statement?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (here paste your query)
```

So your full query will be following

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
SELECT a.QM_ID,a.QM_QCM_ID,
       a.QM_Question,a.QM_Type,
       a.QM_Parent_Id,
       c.AM_Answer, 
       c.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master a 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master c 
             ON (c.AM_QM_ID = a.QM_ID 
                 AND c.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND c.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE a.QM_Parent_Id = 0 
       AND a.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND a.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND a.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       null, 
       null 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0 
       AND b.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@

UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       d.AM_Answer, 
       d.AM_Comments 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_ID 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id IN (SELECT QM_ID 
                            FROM question_master 
                           WHERE QM_Parent_Id = 0 
                                 AND QM_Status = 'A' 
                                 AND QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
                                 AND QM_QRM_Id = %@)
)
```

Comment: When i answer both question the problem in second UNION select query.

Comment: duplicate displaying from below query only UNION
SELECT b.QM_ID,
       b.QM_QCM_ID,
       b.QM_Question,
       b.QM_Type,
       b.QM_Parent_Id,
       null, 
       null 
  FROM question_master b 
       INNER JOIN Assessment_master d 
             ON (d. AM_QM_ID = b.QM_Parent_Id 
                 AND d.AM_HNM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_HM_ID = %d 
                 AND d.AM_ASM_Local_Id = %@) 
 WHERE b.QM_Parent_Id != 0 
       AND b.QM_Status = 'A' 
       AND b.QM_QCM_ID = %@ 
       AND b.QM_QRM_Id = %@